# C# Windows Forms closes immediately

Tags: c#, .net, windows, windows-forms-designer

My app is like this

```
static void Main()
{
    MessageBox.Show("aaa");
    Application.EnableVisualStyles();
    MessageBox.Show("b");
    Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
    MessageBox.Show("c");
    Application.Run(new login());
    MessageBox.Show("d"); 
}
```

Only `MessageBox` is visible on screen, in taskbar appears the application is running but the window form `login()` never shows.

When the last `MessageBox` is closed, the app closes immediately.

I'm a new developer in C# with .NET

Comment: What are you using to write the code? Visual Studio? Notepad? What version of .NET are you using? Where did you get the code from?

Comment: The following may be of interest: https://stackoverflow.com/a/76250905/10024425

Comment: Can you show login's code with text?

Comment: Did you [set `STAThread`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41487381/stathread-requirement-for-windows-forms)?

Comment: The problem you have is not in the code you show, it's in the code for your `login` class. You should be debugging that code. If you are using Visual Studio (or VS Code), use the debugger,  not message boxes to debug things

Answer (score 0):

There is no issue with the code you have shared. If you are able to see the last message box that means, the login form opened & closed.
If you share the code written in login form, then someone can tell why the form is closing by its own.

Hope you are not closing the form using such code.

```
private void login_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Close();
    }
```